# Proving uniqueness of the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I need to prove that for a given $a \in \mathbb{R}, a \geq 0$, there exists a unique monotonic function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(1) = a$. How do I prove uniqueness?
I assumed the opposite and proved that it holds for every natural number via mathematical induction. I do not know what to do next.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I assumed the opposite and proved that it holds for every natural number via mathematical induction. I do not know what to do next.

Comment: What can you deduce about the value at $1/2$? At $1/n$? At rationals? You can [edit] the question, but do not use comments to clarify.

Comment: I do not know where to use the assumption that f is monotonic...

Comment: Hint:  find out what the value of the function must be at every integer.  hint2: find out what it must be for every rational.  Hint3, apply monotonicity and density of rationals.

Comment: Maybe after some simplification you can reduce the problem to Cauchy's functional equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation